# How to configure Socket.io to work with LWC OSS?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss, websockets

I am trying to use [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) library with LWC OSS and followed the below steps:

1. Created LWC OSS app using the command `npx create-lwc-app my-app`
2. Installed socket.io library using the command `npm install socket.io`
3. Updated **scripts/server.js** as below:

   ```
    // Simple Express server setup to serve the build output
    const compression = require('compression');
    const helmet = require('helmet');
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const server = require('http').createServer(express);
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);

    const app = express();
    app.use(helmet());
    app.use(compression());

    const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
    const DIST_DIR = './dist';

    io.on('connection', (client) => {
        console.log(`client connected`);
        client.on('disconnect', () => { 
            console.log(`Client disconnected`);
         });
      });

    app.use(express.static(DIST_DIR));

    app.use('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(DIST_DIR, 'index.html'));
    });

    server.listen(3001, () => {
        console.log('listening on port 3001');
    });
   ```
4. Updated **src/client/modules/my/app/app.js** as below:

   ```
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
    import io from 'socket.io';

    export default class App extends LightningElement {

        connectedCallback() {
            //eslint-disable-next-line
            var socket = io();
        }
    }
   ```
5. Ran the command `npm run watch` and get the below error:

   ```
            ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/John/workspace/my-app/            node_modules/socket.io/dist'
     @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 27:13-26
     @ ./src/client/modules/my/app/app.js
     @ ./src/client/index.js
     @ multi ./node_modules/error-overlay-webpack-plugin/lib/entry-basic.js ./node_modules/             error-overlay-webpack-plugin/lib/entry-devserver.js? ./src/client/index.js
    (node:25805) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,        stat       '/initrd.img'
    (node:25805) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error              originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by              rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:25805) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.         In      the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js      process with a       non-zero exit code.
    (node:25805) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,        stat       '/initrd.img.old'
    (node:25805) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error              originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by              rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
    (node:25805) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,        stat       '/vmlinuz'
    (node:25805) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error              originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by              rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
    (node:25805) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,        stat       '/vmlinuz.old'
    (node:25805) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error              originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by              rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
   ```
6. When I launch url http://localhost:3001, it shows the below error:

   ```
    ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js
    Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/John/workspace/my-app/      node_modules/socket.io/dist'
   ```

Quick google search shows that this is a common known issue with webpack bundling and there are some recommended solutions like in this [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' Using Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932203/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-fs-using-webpack) but I am confused as where to make change like this.

I am guessing ***lwc-services.config.js*** need to be updated to resolve this error but I am not sure as what that change is. Can someone help me here?

Comment: in `scripts/server.js` can you safely add and test the following? 
 Add `const fs = require('fs');` beneath `const io = require('socket.io')(server);`

Comment: @PeterNoges Yes, I am able to access `fs` library without any errors in `scripts/server.js`. It is showing this error only when I add `socket.io` reference in `src/client/modules/my/app/app.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the module that you are using is for the server-side and not the client-side socket.io lib you need. Use the client site [script](https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-3.0.1.min.js) instead.

You can just use the `<script>` tag in your HTML `index.html` and import the socket.io js [file](https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-3.0.1.min.js) for the client site

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io('http://localhost');
</script>
```

You can use the server-side module that you have in your express server.

Comment: nice one Mohith, good to know

Comment: Thanks Mohith for walking through with me on this. Yes, I used server side library, instead of client side library. :facepalm